# Table of contents sidebar in Sphinx LaTeX PDF

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx, hyperref

I am generating a LaTeX document from Sphinx, and converting it to PDF using pdflatex (from MikTeX). The document is missing a table of contents in the sidebar of the PDF viewer.

If I add manually `\usepackage{hyperref}` to the tex file, it works. But how can I tell Sphinx to do it in the conf.py project file? There is no (evident) related option in the latex output options.

Thanks!

Comment: The [Options for LaTeX output](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#latex-options) shows the `latex_elements` option. You can specify a value under `preamble`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that preamble was rst code inserted conditionally when the target is latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section **2.5.3 Customizing the rendering** of the Sphinx document mentions:

> #### LaTeX preamble
>
> Additional commands may be added as preamble in the generated LaTeX file. This is easily done by editing file `conf.py`:
>
> ```
> f = open('latex-styling.tex', 'r+');
> PREAMBLE = f.read();
>
> latex_elements = {
>   # The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
>   #'papersize': 'a4paper',
>
>   # The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
>   #'pointsize': '10pt',
>
>   # Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
>   'preamble': PREAMBLE
> }
> ```
>
> This will copy the contents of file `latex-styling.tex` (in same directory as `conf.py`) to the generated LaTeX document. For instance, if `latex-styling.tex` reads:
>
> ```
> % My personal "bold" command
> \newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
> ```
>
> the generated LaTeX document becomes:
>
> ```
> % Generated by Sphinx.
> \def\sphinxdocclass{report}
> \documentclass[a4paper,10pt,english]{sphinxmanual}
> % snip (packages)
> % My personal "bold" command
> \newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
> \title{My Extension Documentation}
> \date{2013-06-30 22:25}
> \release{1.0.0}
> \author{Xavier Perseguers}
> ```
>
> #### Other options
>
> The configuration file `conf.py` lets you further tune the rendering with LaTeX. Please consult http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#options-for-latex-output for further instructions.

A more direct way of adding content rather than inserting it in a separate file (say, `latex-styling.tex`), is to specify if verbatim. The next subsection in the documentation mentions this for a specific package `typo3`:

> #### TYPO3 template
>
> We want to stick as much as possible to default rendering, to avoid having to change the LaTeX code generation from Sphinx. As such, we choose to include a custom package `typo3` (file `typo3.sty`) that will override some settings of package `sphinx`. To include it automatically, we simply use the `preamble` option of `conf.py`:
>
> ```
> latex_elements = {
>   # Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
>   'preamble': '\\usepackage{typo3}'
> }
> ```

It's better to contain your styling options in a separate `latex-styling.tex` file that you can include using the `preamble` key via an `f.read()`. That way you don't have to update `conf.py`. Compartmentalization is usually better.

Comment: While creating LatexPdf from Sphinx project I find that the hyperlinks which are there in the generated **html documentation** are missing in the **pdf** file. I have included `hyperref` in the `conf.py` **preamble**. Can **some links** be provided to get a head up on this?